# Problem : space for footer is not the same for the first page

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm making header and footer with fancydr. The problem is that the space between the bottom of the page and the footer is not the same on the first page than in the others.
I've checked that the space is reported to the header.

Thanks for your attention.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}          
\rhead{bla blat\\bla bla\\bla bla}  
\lhead{\large{\textbf{bla}}}
\lfoot{bla}
\cfoot{bla}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please note that questions on this site should be asked in English only.  Your English needs not be perfect, of course, but please try to translate your question in elementary English as far as you can.

Comment: Did you see the `fancyhdr` warning regarding `\headheight`: "Package Fancyhdr Warning: `\headheight` is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 39.00421pt.  We now make it that large for the rest of the document. This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however." So you have to enlarge `\headheight` at least to the suggested value.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of my explanation but here is a workaround.

1. first case your code with package showframe
2. Second one, I add the geometry package to set the header height.

Here the code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage[a4paper, margin={2cm,3cm}, headheight=3cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}          
\rhead{bla blat\\bla bla\\bla bla}  
\lhead{\large{\textbf{bla}}}
\lfoot{bla}
\cfoot{bla}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin={2cm,3cm}, headheight=3cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}          
\rhead{bla blat\\bla bla\\bla bla}  
\lhead{\large{\textbf{bla}}}
\lfoot{bla}
\cfoot{bla}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]